# SOAP WSDL not generating

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I am new to `SOAP Web Services` and developed a basic application. While running the application it runs fine. When I am trying to see the WSDL file by appending **?wsdl** at end of the URL but it does show an error.

I have even tested the same with SOAP UI but it throws an error:
**WSDLException (at /html): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.**

Below is the code:

```
package com.WS.Book;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class BookDetails {
    @WebMethod
    public List<String> getBook() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("Book 1");
        list.add("Book 2");
        list.add("Book 3");
        return list;
    }
}
```

Please do let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: have you tried opening it in a web browser and saving it using .wsdl extension?

Comment: I had tried it on web browser (url?wsdl) but still does not return wsdl format

Comment: Please add also how did you deploy the service and which URL are you using to get the WSDL.

Comment: I have deployed it on Apache Tomcat and the URL used is http://localhost:8080/Day2_Demo1_CreateWS?wsdl.